# How to build a clickable button using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my Code, I have just created a box and added some text to it. I am not sure if it works or not. The purpose is to build a clickable button. Any suggestion and help will be appreciated.

```
//create Button
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let bthHeight = 40;
let btnWidth = 100;
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
ctx.fillRect(20,20,btnHeight,btnWidth);

//Add Button innerText
ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Login",btnHeight/2,btnWidth/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Possible cause of errors:

Error at line 2:

```
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function
```

In this case, change the tag with id `myCanvas` to `<canvas>`

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

---

typo while initializing the button height: change `bthHeight` to `btnHeight`

```
let btnHeight = 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add fill as a new `Path2D` and listen `mousedown` event on canvas element. Pass the clicked location and the path to `isPointInPath` and implement depending on the result.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//create Button
const btnHeight = 40;
const btnWidth = 100;
const btnX = 20;
const btnY = 20
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
const button = new Path2D();
button.rect(btnX,btnY,btnWidth,btnHeight);
ctx.fill(button);

//Add Button innerText
ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign="center"; 
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("Login",btnX + 0.5*btnWidth,btnY + 0.5*btnHeight);


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(button, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)) {
    alert("clicked inside");
  }
  else {
    alert("clicked outside");
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" />
```